# Turning XAML context menu into resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to edit some code so that a context menu is contained in the resources of a xaml file rather than within the actual code. The context menu is:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="CameraControlContextMenu" x:Shared="False" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <exclusiveMenuItem:ExclusiveMenuItem x:Name="Turn" Header="{DynamicResource SetCameraToTurn}" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsTurnMode}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action TurnMode]" IsEnabled="{Binding IsAvailable}" Icon="{DynamicResource TurningImageSource}"/>
    <exclusiveMenuItem:ExclusiveMenuItem x:Name="Drag" Header="{DynamicResource SetCameraToDrag}" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsDragMode}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action DragMode]" Icon="{DynamicResource DragImageSource}"/>            
</ContextMenu>
```

Anyway, the context menu works fine and was located within another menu:

```
<splitButton:SplitButton.DropDownContextMenu>
    CONTEXTMENUWASHERE
</splitButton:SplitButton.DropDownContextMenu>
```

I'm trying to extract it into the XAML file's resources so I can use it in more than one place. I'm having a bit of trouble though. I've taken it out fine, the problem is referencing the context menu in the resources from within that splitbutton there.

My XAML is a little shaky and I'm finding this a bit tricky to research, although I imagine the solution is probably something very simple.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see your problem, or perhaps I've either misunderstood it, or you're just not seeing the wood for the trees? How about setting the `ContextMenu` on your control in the normal short XAML form:

```
<splitButton:SplitButton 
    DropDownContextMenu="{StaticResource CameraControlContextMenu}" />
```

Comment: Hm, that's telling me "cannot set properties on property elements".

Comment: I don't know anything about your `SplitButton` control because you didn't show us. Going by typical shorthand XAML conventions alone, this is how you would set the `DropDownContextMenu` property, judging by your longhand XAML example. I cannot tell you any more than that.